# Browser cookie storage

Tags: javascript, cookies, save, load, autosave

I am making a browser game where it is import to save data to keep your progress. This is the code I am using to save each variable:

```js
function autosave() {
  localStorage.setItem("variablename", variablename);
}
setInterval(autosave, 1000);
```

However, it has come to my attention that browsers such as chrome can only store 50 cookies per domain. Does each variable count as one cookie? If so, how can I work around this.

Comment: That's not a cookie.

Comment: localStorage and cookies are not the same thing.

Comment: You should check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220660/local-storage-vs-cookies

Comment: Thanks guys, I had no clue they were different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

localStorage and cookies are different.

If you're curious about the limits of localStorage check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989284/what-is-the-max-size-of-localstorage-values).

Answer (score 2):

You said 'Cookies' Right? Here is a method from [tutorialsrepublic.com](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/javascript-tutorial/javascript-cookies.php)

To set Cookies

```
function setCookie(name, value, daysToLive = undefined) {
    // Encode value in order to escape semicolons, commas, and whitespace
    var cookie = name + "=" + encodeURIComponent(value);
    
    if (typeof daysToLive === "number") {
        /* Sets the max-age attribute so that the cookie expires
        after the specified number of days */
        cookie += "; max-age=" + (daysToLive*24*60*60);
    }
        
    document.cookie = cookie;
}
```

To get Cookies

```
function getCookie(name) {
    // Split cookie string and get all individual name=value pairs in an array
    var cookieArr = document.cookie.split(";");
    
    // Loop through the array elements
    for(var i = 0; i < cookieArr.length; i++) {
        var cookiePair = cookieArr[i].split("=");
        
        /* Removing whitespace at the beginning of the cookie name
        and compare it with the given string */
        if(name == cookiePair[0].trim()) {
            // Decode the cookie value and return
            return decodeURIComponent(cookiePair[1]);
        }
    }
    
    // Return null if not found
    return null;
}
```

And to reassign cookies, just use the same one as set.

```
setCookie(Name, NewValue, Days)
```

Example:

Finally, to delete cookies you can use

```
setCookie(Name, '', 0)
```

For Localstorage, [Go here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: Thankyou but it has come to my attention that I am not talking about cookies, rather local storage.

Comment: How do I do that, sorry I’m new

Comment: Check at the bottom; I added a link to MDN